# Erro wamp 0xc000007b

Tags: php, wamp

Ola, estou com um problema no mysql no meu Wamp.

Já testei inúmeras versões do sistema e sempre dá esse erro.

Ja coloquei as dlls msvcr110.dll e msvcr120.dll

Já tentei instalar todas as distribuições do c++ nesse notebook.

Não sei oque fazer mais

Tenho um lenovo thinkpad t450 com 500 gb de ssd e 16 gb de ram.

Obrigado desde já

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse erro costuma ser algo relacionado a algum programa faltando mesmo desde as distribuições de C++ as do net framework, se quiser fazer um "update massivo" de coisas pra ter certeza recomendo o [AIO da Sereby](https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/all-in-one-runtimes/), está em alemão mas é bem intuitivo no que faz:
Site deles (https://www.sereby.org/)

Comment: faka felipe, obrigado pela resposta, fiz aqui e continua com o mesmo erro